# Replace all values in multiple columns by looking up values from a reference data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, mutate

I'm looking to replace values in multiple columns of a data frame: `df_skeleton` with corresponding values from a reference data frame: `df_ref`.

I'd like to replace each value conditionally based on the following conditions:

1. df_skeleton column name matches a substring found in df_ref column name
2. df_skeleton ID value matches a substring found in df_ref column name
3. df_skeleton$`Date Time` == df_ref$`Date Time`

Column names in `df_ref` follow a pattern: identifier (e.g., A1), -, and a descriptor (e.g., Phase). Using regex, I'd like to match the `Date Time` columns in both data frames, both the identifier and descriptor in `df_ref` column names with `ID` in `df_skeleton` and column name to locate the replacement value (found in `df_ref`).

---

```
df_ref <-tibble(`Date Time` = c(seq(ymd_hm("2023-1-1 0:00"), ymd_hm("2023-1-1 5:00"), by = "hour")),
    `A1 - Phase` = c("NA", "Stdby", "Stdby", "Active", "Active", "Active"),
    `A1 - Value` = seq(1, 12, by = 2),
    `B1 - Phase` = c("NA", "NA", "Stdby", "Active", "Active", "Active"),
    `B1 - Value` = seq(2, 7, by = 1))
```

```
df_skeleton <- tibble(`Date Time` = rep(seq(ymd_hm("2023-1-1 0:00"), ymd_hm("2023-1-1 5:00"), by = "hour"), 2),
                     ID = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1"),
                     Phase = 1790,
                     `Value` = 1790)
```

```
df_desired_output <- tibble(`Date Time` = rep(seq(ymd_hm("2023-1-1 0:00"), ymd_hm("2023-1-1 5:00"), by = "hour"), 2),
                     ID = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1"),
                     Phase = c("NA", "Stdby", "Stdby", "Active", "Active", "Active", "NA", "NA", "Stdby", "Active", "Active", "Active"),
                     `Value` = c("1", "3", "5", "7", "9", "11", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df_ref %>% 
  #converts the data type for merging variables in the next layer
  mutate(`A1 - Value` = as.character(`A1 - Value`)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1) %>% 
  separate(name, c("ID","PV")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="PV", values_from="value") %>% 
  mutate(Value = as.double(Value))
```